# Using drush up with --gitinfofile

Tags: drush, installation, updating

I tried to manage drupal modules with the --package_handler=git_drupalorg which needed me to add the --gitinfofile option. Using drush dl this works but if I try to update my modules with drush up the version information is the same as of the drush dl version.
Is there a fix for this or a guide which explains how to use drush with the git version control system.
I am using the drush 6.2.0 version.

Comment: Come on. No one using this feature and has the same problem? What is your workflow then?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments below, the actual answer here is that the [git deploy](https://drupal.org/project/git_deploy) module is required for `--package-handler=git_drupalorg` to work correctly.

If you just want to track the latest HEAD from some branch of some module, then you can use `drush dl` with `--package-handler=git_drupalorg` to download the file, and use `git pull` when you want to update your code.

`drush pm-updatecode` is best used in instances where you wish to track the latest stable release of the module.

Comment: The problem is not using drush `drush dl` or `drush upc`. The problem is using `dl` with `--gitinfofile` updates the .info file correctly while using `upc` or `up` does **not** change the version information in the .info file.
This way the update status becomes outdated and even wrong as the code is version 1.1 and .info says `version = "7.x-1.0"`.

Comment: I found that trying to use `--gitinfofile` is more complicated than helpfull. I tried the module [git_deploy](https://drupal.org/project/git_deploy) and it seems to do the trick even as I thought this shouldn't be required any more.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are correct -- git_deploy is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution that has worked well for me, but requires a 1-line hack of a drush file, **so use it at your own risk**. Really the only problem is to remember to redo the hack when you upgrade drush. Below I broke it all down for completeness.

1) For download

> drush pm-download MODULE_NAME --package-handler=git_drupalorg --gitinfofile

2) For update

> drush pm-update MODULE_NAME --package-handler=git_drupalorg --gitinfofile --gitcheckoutparams=-f

To make these your default options, add the following to sites/all/drush/drushrc.php

```
$options['package-handler'] = 'git_drupalorg';
$command_specific['pm-download'] = array('gitinfofile' => TRUE);
$command_specific['pm-update'] = array('gitinfofile' => TRUE, 'gitcheckoutparams' => '-f');
$command_specific['pm-updatecode'] = array('gitinfofile' => TRUE, 'gitcheckoutparams' => '-f');
```

3) Put the following hook in sites/all/drush/SITENAME.drush.inc

```
/**
* Implements HOOK_pm_post_update().
* NOTE: Bottom section of package_handler_post_download($project, $release)
*       from file PATH2DRUSH/drush/commands/pm/package_handler/git_drupalorg.inc
*/
function SITENAME_pm_post_update($project) {
  $release = $project['releases'][$project['candidate_version']];
  if (drush_get_option('gitinfofile', FALSE)) {
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/^(.+).x-dev$/', $release['version'], $matches)) {
      $full_version = drush_pm_git_drupalorg_compute_rebuild_version($project['full_project_path'], $matches[1]);
    }
    else {
      $full_version = $release['version'];
    }
    drush_pm_inject_info_file_metadata($project['full_project_path'], $project['name'], $full_version);
  }
}
```

4) Hack drush file PATH2DRUSH/drush/commands/pm/updatecode.pm.inc

```
/**
 * Run the post-update hooks after updatecode is complete for one project.
 */
function pm_update_complete($project, $version_control) {
  drush_print(dt('Project !project was updated successfully. Installed version is now !version.', array('!project' => $project['name'], '!version' => $project['candidate_version'])));
  // HACK - send over entire $project to all HOOK_pm_post_update implementations
  //drush_command_invoke_all('pm_post_update', $project['name'], $project['releases'][$project['candidate_version']]);
  drush_command_invoke_all('pm_post_update', $project);
  $version_control->post_update($project);
}
```

Comment: Does git deploy not do the trick for you? You can remove your addition to pm_update_complete if you rename your hook to drush_SITENAME_post_pm_updatecode. You can recover $project via `$updated = drush_get_context('DRUSH_PM_UPDATED');`.  $updated is an array of $project(s).